# Access return code of last command in AWK

Tags: awk, exit-status

Command not found should produce return code `127`:

```
$ foo; echo $?
bash: foo: command not found...
127
```

I tried to assign `$?` to variable `rc` and then print it, but RC is always `0`.

```
$ foo | awk -v rc="$?" 'BEGIN{print rc}'
0
bash: foo: command not found...
```

Found out that it will print correct RC only in this case:

```
$ qazqaz
bash: qazqaz: command not found...
$ foo | awk -v rc="$?" 'BEGIN{print rc}'
127
bash: foo: command not found...
```

Is it possible to work with RC in awk while pipes are used? Or is the problem somewhere else?

I would like to stick to some old portable awk implementation.

Comment: Why are you trying to pipe the output of a non-existent command?

Comment: Because somewhere it is present, somewhere it's not.

Comment: Use a semicolon for your awk version, like you did for the first (working ) example

Comment: @val0x00ff I expected something like that. Tried, same result.

Comment: @JeffSchaller You are right! But this was just simplified example - I will work with the output in awk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a pipeline, commands run concurrently. That's the whole point, the output of one is fed to the other in real time.

You only know the exit status of a command when it returns. If you wanted `awk` to process the output of `foo` and also get access to its exit status, you'd need to run `awk` *after* `foo` after having stored `foo`'s output somewhere like:

```
foo > file
awk -v "rc=$?" '{print rc, $0}' < file
```

Alternatively, you could have `awk` run `foo` by itself (well, still via a shell to interpret a command line), read its output (through a pipe via its `cmd | getline` interface to `popen()`) and get its exit status with:

```
awk -v cmd=foo '
  BEGIN {
    while ((cmd | getline) > 0) {
      print
    }
    rc = close(cmd)
    print rc
  }'
```

However note that the way `awk` encodes the exit status varies from one `awk` implementation to the next. In some it's the status straight as returned by `waitpid()` or `pclose()`, in others it's that one divided by 256 (even when `foo` is killed by a signal)... though you should be able to rely on `rc` being 0 if and only if the command was successful.

In the case of `gawk`, [it did change recently](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2016-03/msg00006.html).

Or you could have the exit status fed at the end through the pipe:

```
(foo; echo "$?") | awk '
   {saved = $0}
   NR > 1 {
     # process the previous line
     $0 = prev
     print "output:", $0
   }
   {prev = saved}
   END{rc = prev; print rc}'
```

(assuming `foo`'s output ends in a newline character when it's not empty (is valid text)).

Or fed through a separate pipe. For instance on Linux and with a shell other than ksh93:

```
{ : extra pipe | { (foo 3<&-; echo "$?" > /dev/fd/3) | awk '
  {print}
  END {getline rc < "/dev/fd/3"; print rc}'
} 3<&0 <&4 4<&-; } 4<&0
```

Comment: Seems like the most viable option for me. I just wanted to avoid temp files or running commands within awk exactly because of those compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the type command and so:

```
type test > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
0

type fsfsf > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
1
```